# SQL injection attack(hacker posting spam hyperlinks) into our sql db columns.

Tags: sql-injection

does anyone know why our website is getting these sql injection attacks (the hacker posts spam paydayloan hyperlinks into our database columns)? I know how to remove the error just not find the solution in the first place. thanks ricky

Comment: What server side scripting language are you using? PHP with `mysql_` calls to the database?

Comment: And also what software (such as Wordpress or phpBB) are you using?  It's worth mentioning *everything*, including tools like phpMyAdmin, even if you think they are only used by you.

Answer (score 1):

most data access implenmentation take care of injection for you.
use prepared statements / bind variables instead of string concatenation.